# Can you translate a question — in the form No + gerund? — as Aucun + infinitif?

Tags: traduction

1. I'm changing the facts of [this post](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/no-chipmunking.3766710/). Imagine that you're uncertain, and are asking the following as interrogative questions in French. Don't construe them as forbiddances or proscriptions. 1. Can you translate "No belching, burping, or excessive chipmunking?" as

> Aucun roter, éructer et stocker de nourriture dans ses joues ?

I know that you can translate this as, and I'm NOT asking about

> Peut-on roter, peut-on éructer, et peut-on stocker de nourriture dans ses joues?

2. As another example, can you translate "No soliciting?" **as a question** as

> Aucun démarcher? Aucun colporter?

Notice I used the infinitive, not the nouns [*démarchage* or  *colportage*](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/no-soliciting-on-a-sign.3518831/post-17878691).

Comment: What exactly would "No + gerund?" mean, as a question? It's typically something you'd see on a sign, I don't see how you can use that in a question. Do you have any examples?

Comment: **Défense de [substantif ou verbe]**. In English, **No [verb]**

Comment: Pas de ..., Ne pas ..., Défense de ..., Prière de ne pas ..., Il est interdit de ..., Interdiction de ..., Aucune ..., etc. You can use aucun(e) but you have to use the noun form, although it's problematic since they can have different genres.

Comment: @Lambie No. I'm not referring to forbiddances or proscriptions. I'm referring to "No infinitive?" as questions. See [wazoox's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/47202) that understood my question.

Comment: @Simon No. I'm not referring to forbiddances or proscriptions. I'm referring to "No infinitive?" as questions. See [wazoox's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/47202) that understood my question.

Comment: Changing *On ne rote pas, on n'éructe pas, on ne stocke pas de nourriture dans ses joues!* (affirmative) into *Peut-on roter, peut-on éructer, et peut-on stocker de nourriture dans ses joues?* (interrogative) makes it an entirely different question. And in this [comment](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/47194/can-you-translate-a-question-in-the-form-no-gerund-as-aucun-infinitif/47196?noredirect=1#comment95889_47202) it seems you are still asking for something else.

Answer (score 2):

1 -  Regarding the vocabulary:

- *Aucun* being a determiner it can only be used in front of a noun, it cannot be used in front of a verb, and although the French infinitive can in some cases be used a a noun, it is not the case here. To negate a verb in French you have to use *ne pas*.
- I would translate "belch" by *éructer* (the educated word) and "burp" (marked as slang in the OED) by *roter* (more familiar).

2 - There are numerous ways one could say what you want using an infinitive in French, with nuances though, and I expect none as neutral as the "no+gerund" form in English.

- **a**) *Il est interdit d'éructer, de roter et de trop se remplir la bouche de nourriture*<sup>1</sup>.
- **b**) *On est prié de ne pas éructer, de ne pas roter et de ne pas trop se remplir la bouche de nourriture*.  (Or : *prière de*...)
  Which is slightly more polite.
- **c**) *Ne pas éructer, ne pas roter et ne pas trop se remplir la bouche de nourriture*.
  Would sound neutral and closer to the English "no+gerund" form and would be grammatically correct but I expect it will rarely be found. Personally I would expect something after that, such as *sous peine de punition*<sup>2</sup>.

3 - A sign with "No soliciting" would be *[Démarchage interdit](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22d%C3%A9marchage%20interdit%22&lr=&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlg4ye07zyAhWmzoUKHVjqAN4Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1860&bih=909)*. *Il est interdit de démarcher* is correct French but I expect it would hardly be found.

I am not sure I understand what you mean when you say "as a question". In English "No soliciting?" is a question in as much as you end the sentence with a question mark. The same can be done in French, just replace the period by a question mark.

---

**Edit** after the question has been edited.

Now that the question has been modified not to ask about
*On ne rote pas, on n'éructe pas, on ne stocke pas de nourriture dans ses joues!* (affirmative) but about *On ne rote pas, on n'éructe pas, on ne stocke pas de nourriture dans ses joues?* (interrogative) I will add:

**1-** What I stated and explained in my original answer still holds and you cannot use *aucun*, which is a determiner, in front of a verb. If you want to write a question you can, just as you do in your English sentence, add a question mark and when speaking modify your intonation so that it follows the question pattern.

*Ne pas éructer, ne pas roter et ne pas trop se remplir la bouche de nourriture **?***

**2-** In a comment you say that you wanted to ask "Could you [do something] no belching, burping, or excessive chipmunking?", which is yet something different. But the vocabulary and grammar remarks still hold.

- If your infinitive were directly dependent of *pouvoir* you would have :
  *Pourriez-vous (pourrais-tu) ne pas éructer, ne pas roter et ne pas trop te (vous) remplir  la bouche de nourriture ?*
- But the infinitives *éructer, roter,...* depend on an action (modified by *pouvoir*) and what you really mean is "can you do something **without** belching...". "Without" in French is ***sans*** and you cannot omit *sans*.

  - *Peux-tu manger en silence, sans parler* ?
  - *Pourrais-tu (pourriez-vous) [faire ceci] sans éructer, sans roter et sans trop te (vous) remplir la bouche ?*

**3.**
In the same way you could say :

- *Sans démarcher ? Sans colporter ?*
  *Peut-on distribuer des publicités sans démarcher, sans colporter ?*

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>The craze of food contests has not yet reached France and "chipmunking" has no standard equivalent. If I wanted to stay close to the image of the chipmunk I would say *se gonfler les joues de nourriture* but I am not sure a French native who hasn't heard of food contests would know what I am talking about.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> One could read on a street sign :
[*Jeter son masque sur la voie publique est puni de 68 € d'amende*.](https://twitter.com/PoliceNat91/status/1262383509055909895)</sup>

Comment: @Lambie Apology for not writing my question more clearly. I'm not referring to forbiddances or proscriptions. I'm referring to "No infinitive?" as questions. See [wazoox's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/47202) that understood my question.

Comment: @user52144 I think I had answered this part of your question "Can you translate "No belching, burping, or excessive chipmunking?" as "Aucun roter, éructer et stocker de nourriture dans ses joues ?"  explaining why *aucun* is impossible in front of an infinitive verb.  In addition I have tried to correct the vocabulary issues in your question.  I have now edited my question following the modification in your question. P.S. I expect your comment was meant for me although you addressed it to Lambie?

Answer (score 0):

**I** No, those forms are not correct in French; you have to use nouns, and at that there is no way to use the adjective "aucun" in this case; since the person is giving an order without using a verb, "pas de" is the usual negative locution; this is one of the usual formats of indications given by means of signs.

- Pas de rots, de renvois, ni de stockage de nourriture dans la bouche.

Otherwise, the use of "aucun" becomes possible.

- Je ne veux entendre aucun rot ou renvoi, et je ne veux aucun stockage de nourriture dans la bouche.

Note: 1/ "stocker  de la nourriture dans les/ses joues" is not idiomatic because of the definition.

2/ The use of both "rot" and "renvoi" would be strange in French, because those words are synonyms. The same applies to English, as far as I can see; I don't quite get the idea in this repetition.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rot)) Pop., fam. Émission bruyante de gaz stomacaux par la bouche. Synon. éructation, renvoi.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/joue)) A. − [Chez l'homme] 1 Partie latérale de la face délimitée par le dessous de l'œil, la tempe et le menton.

**II** No again, the same principles apply.

- Pas de démarchage, pas de colportage

Comment: In English, a belch is typically louder, more open-mouthed, more sonorous, ruder. It's a big burp. The smallest burp can be almost a hiccup, whereas what Barney Gumbel on the Simpsons does is a belch.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Dictionaries seem to be all failing in making that precise; the translation is a problem then. It is true that in French "renvoi" is not used for that sort of "unrestrained behaviour" that can be caused by much beer drinking but instead for the quasi unconscious behaviour of babies, whereas "rot" is.

Comment: Pas de rots, de renvois, ni de stockage de nourriture dans la bouche.  usual formats of indications given by means of signs.?? That is French and English? *stocker la nourriture dans la bouche*??  No [verb] is Défense de [verbe ou substantif].'

Comment: @Lambie Apology for not writing my question more clearly. I'm not referring to forbiddances or proscriptions. I'm referring to "No infinitive?" as questions. See [wazoox's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/47202) that understood my question.

Answer (score 0):

Without more context it's hard to tell. If by a question you  mean something  like:

"Could you drink a gallon of beer, no belching?"

You'd use in French this form:
"Pourrais-tu boire *sans roter*, *sans baver*, etc?"

Comment: Apology for not writing my question more clearly. But you understood my question! Yes, I intended to mean something like "Could you drink a gallon of beer, no belching?"